# Detecting Integer Comparison conditional in LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){
    unsigned short int a = 10;
    if (a == 10){
     //something
    }
}
```

In an LLVM pass, how would I detect 2 operand integer comparison conditional statements like the one shown above: (a == 10)? Please let me know what I should look for in the LLVM api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is an [ICmpInst](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ICmpInst.html) whose operands are integers. Since both operands have to have the same type, `isa<ICmpInst>(foo) && isa<IntegerType>(foo->getOperand(0))` is enough to identify whether a particular instruction is the kind you want to detect.